# UV of cube after transform

Tags: uv, transforms

In my project I have a cube, this cube was transformed(Scale) and now I trying make texture for this cube. But if I selecting the face of this cube in UV editor I getting just cube(Square) not transformed.

My goal is make texture with proportions of transformed cube.

I tried clicks to all buttons in Blender - really. And tried to triangulate, rebuild or something like this, also as I understand unwrap it is not what I need.

*picture of compare of transformed face and the uv of this face:
[image]

**same question:
[Why this cube have this scale in Uv Unwrap?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283217/why-this-cube-have-this-scale-in-uv-unwrap)

Comment: Hello and welcome. when you edit the 3D mesh, the UVs are not going to auto-update to match the new dimesions of the Mesh, you need to UV unwrap after you finish the 3D mesh editing

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Emir i tried unwrap but this face still be square, thanks for answer maybe it is bug

Comment: @moonboots bazylevnik0.github.io/art/side/dribbble/card/card+.blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the scale of your object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and unwrap again:

[image]